# Is the point of multi-threading to increase your CPU usage?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, cpu, cpu-architecture

I am very new to the concept of multi-threading, but to my understanding the whole point of multi-threading architecture (I learnt there is hardware multi-threading and software multi-threading; not that I completely understand the concept of each but I think I am talking about the hardware aspect here) is to "keep your CPU busy". This is for example to process another task when your current one is fetching your hard-disk for data import.

If I am correct, for a non multi-threading CPU, if it already has near 100% usage, then switching to a multi-threading one would not help you much. Am I correct?

I am sure my statement of the problem is full of inaccuracy but I hope I made myself understood.

Comment: You are right that adding multi-threading to a 100% loaded CPU will not help, but I would not say *"the point of multi-threading is to keep your CPU busy"*, rather that the point is *"to get your job done sooner"*.

Comment: For CPU-bound computations, it's to take advantage of multi-core CPUs, which you can't do with a single thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've originally misunderstood the question. Your statement is correct for software multi-threading when we parallelize some algorithm to make the computations in multiple threads. In this case if your CPU is already loaded with work you can't make it work faster by executing code in multiple threads. Moreover, you can even expect decrease in performance due to overhead of multi-threaded communications and context switches. But in modern world it is not easy to find a single core CPU (with exception of embedded applications). So in most cases you need to use threads to fully utilize CPU's computational ability.

But for hardware multi-threading situation is different because it is an absolutely different thing. CPU has circuits that perform arithmetic operations and circuits responsible for program flow. And now we make a trick: we double number of second circuits and make them share arithmetic operations circuits. Now two threads can execute **different** commands simultaneously: they can't do summation at the same time, but one can add numbers and second can divide something. And that's how performance is gained. So 100% load now is different load because you have enabled additional circuits in the CPU. Relative value is the same, but absolute performance is higher.

Comment: That't not quite right.  With one CPU, you can't change the minimum amount of CPU time that is invested.  But, if the application uses multiple threads to manage I/O, and it can keep the I/O running in parallel with the computation, the entire program run can be significantly shortened, precisely because the I/O happens in parallel with computation rather than having to wait for all other computatations to finish before the I/O operation occurs.

Comment: @IraBaxter when a thread does IO it does not spend CPU time. So your statement is right, but wudanao has given a precondition that CPU load is 100% and in such situation adding more threads will not increase performance. Anyway, it occurs that wudanao has meant another  multi-threading. I've updated the answer.

Comment: A nit:  A thread doing I/O *does* do computation.  It may do a little or a lot depending on what the I/O requires.   For most I/O operations on most devices, it doesn't do a lot.   What matters here is the overlap of I/O with other computing.

Comment: No. A thread that does IO does NOT compute anything. When it executes commands on CPU it does not perform IO at that particular moment. When it waits for IO it does not execute anything on CPU because it waits for IO. That;s definition of IO. But that does not matter: if you have 100% CPU load you are CPU bounded. You may make IO or not make IO, you are still CPU bounded. Adding threads will not bring speedup because you are CPU bounded, not IO bounded.

Comment: I have built a number of multithreaded OSes in the past; if you have a computation that talks to an I/O device, it uses cycles to decide what to say to the I/O next; if nothing else, it has to have at least a call to "wait event".  If it is *actually hung waiting for event* it doesn't use cycles.  Between events it has to use CPU.  The argument is how much.  Speedup comes in wall clock time:  If an I/O thread doesn't get scheduled because everything else is busy, its I/O never gets accomplished until the other computations finish. I it is scheduled early and doesn't use much, the I/O happens.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment - I was actually not thinking of a single core CPU from the beginning. But rather a multi-core one but each core has utilized its cpu power to almost 100%. In this case, does adding a SMT architecture to the hardware still help?

Comment: @AlexeyGuseynov Thanks for the great answer! Now it seems to me SMT is increasingly similar to adding a core (though I know the difference is that SMT cannot perform two same tasks simultaneously).

Sorry if this question is not very program related - what's the point of enabling SMT than adding a core then? I mean if you have to change the structure of your chip so drastically you might as well...

Comment: The point is that you add only a fraction of circuits needed for a real core. They take less place on crystal so you can place more processors on a plate and resulting CPU is cheaper.

Answer (score 5):

You have been given the task to build a house, your team is composed by you, the supervisor, and a pool of workers.

When your boss came by to check on the progresses, what would you like him to see? One worker doing all the job and the other watching, or all the workers being busy?

You want to keep the worker busy giving them independent tasks, the more worker the harder this is.
Furthermore there are some issues to take into account: worker *A* was given the task to building a wall, and it is building it. Before the wall gets too tall the concrete need to dry, so *A* spends a lot of time waiting.
During this wait they could help somewhere else.
Asking *A* to help somewhere else while they are in the building-the-wall step is pointless, they either need to decline or stop what they are doing.
One way or the other you won't get any benefit.

---

The workers are the equivalent of threads.
The house building is the equivalent of a multi-threaded process.
The *A* worker building the wall is the equivalent of  CPU bounded process, a process that use a CPU as much as he need.
The concrete drying is the equivalent of an IO operation, it will complete itself without the need of any worker.
The *A* worker waiting for the concrete to dry is the equivalent of a IO bounded process, it mostly does nothing.
The *A* worker being always busy is the equivalent of an optimal scheduling/multi-threaded algorithm.

---

Now you are given the task to study a CS book, your team is composed by you, a student that cannot read, and a pool of readers.

How would you assign the readers? You can't make them read each chapter individually, as you can't listen to more than one person.

So even if you have a lot of worker you pick one and make them read the book sequentially.

Reading a book is an example of an inherently sequential problem that won't benefit from multi-threading, while building an house is an example of a very parallelizable problem.

---

Handling multiple workers is not easy: a worker *A* may starts a wall because they took a look at the concrete stash and realized there was enough of it but didn't claim it. Worker *B* needs some concrete and takes it from the stash, now *A* no longer has enough concrete.
This is the equivalent of a race condition: *A* is checking and using a resource in two different times (as two different, divisible, operations) and the result depends on the timing of the workers.

---

If you think of the CPU as "units that can do things"  you will realize that having more "units that can do things" is better only if they are not standing there glazing at the infinity.
Hence all the literature about multi-threading.

Comment: If you like animated-GIF videos, [this one is a pretty hilarious human analogy for a single-threaded process running on a multi-core CPU](http://imgur.com/gallery/mV9bFz7).  Actually, even if you don't normally like animated GIFs, this one is worth watching, and I say this as someone that doesn't normally like animated GIFs or stupid memes.

Comment: @PeterCordes XD CPU0 even has thermal control!